# Transfer files from local to AWS server using SSH in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, paramiko

I devloped a code that is to transfer files from local to AWS server using SSH. The code is worked locally but issue is after converting python package to executable(.exe) file when i run that executable file (file not found)error is raised. That error is key_filename path issue.
Here is my code :

```
import paramiko
from captured_images import function_name
import os

HOST = Host
COMMAND = "ls"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

def imgfun():
    while True:
        newimg = function_name()
        x = newimg.run()
        ssh.connect(hostname=IP, username=username, key_filename=Key_filename)
        sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()
    
        sftp_client.put(scource path, destination path)
    
        sftp_client.close()
        ssh.close()
        
imgfun()
```

Here the error is path issue. So is there any other way to connect AWS server for transferring files from local to AWS server without key_filename.

Thanks all
Swaroop

Comment: If you are getting `file not found` error, your file paths are wrong. Changing tool will not fix it if you keep using wrong file paths.

Comment: conversion of .py with keyfilename to .exe file is it possible ? can we please explain

Comment: Exactly, I'm asking how to embed your key file to the same .exe file that contains your Python code?